# Is it possible to listen to a signal for when a systemd service has crashed/restarted?

Tags: systemd, services, ipc

This is a bit of a newbie question on systemd services, but let's say we have two systemd daemons, and for one of them its important to know whether the other one has crashed or restarted. Is it possible to listen to this event, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use normal IPC for this.  Shared-memory or sockets directly between the two processes.

If your program is written in C, you can use systemd's `#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>`. This is a wrapper around systemd's dbus interface. You can monitor units from here.  You can subscribe to the unit's "PropertiesChanged" member which is emitted whenever any property has changed.  When that signal has changed, query the "ActiveState" member.

There's a good example here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527350/272848