# How to use sd_bus_match_signal() with file descriptor

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I am implementing a DBus signals listener as a part of bigger application.

All of the examples, first register callback to signal with `sd_bus_match_signal()` and them they have a `sd_event_loop()` [LINK](https://gitlab.com/franks_reich/systemd-by-example#listeningtod-bussignals) or raw `while` loop with calls to `sd_bus_wait()` and `sd_bus_process()` [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527350)

My app includes a system for monitoring file descriptors for events. It triggers a callback when a descriptor is ready, similar to how `select()` works for sockets.

How I can integrate DBus listening into my system.

I assume I should utilize `sd_bus_get_fd()`, but how does it connect to invoking the appropriate callback set in `sd_bus_match_signal()`?